# Calling UIActionSheet that is placed in AppDelegate from outside AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiactionsheet, uiapplicationdelegate, uiwindow

I have a `UIActionSheet` in my AppDelegate that is called by:

```
- (void)showActionSheet {
    UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Call Lilly" otherButtonTitles:@"Email IMCLONE Trials", @"Email EmergingMed", nil];
    [sheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
}
```

I need to call it from `AnotherViewController`. In the controller I have:

```
[(LYAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] showActionSheet];
```

... and this doesn't work. I get the error:

```
[3990:207] *** Assertion failure in -[UIActionSheet _presentSheetFromView:above:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UIActionSheet.m:1747
```

I am assuming that the issue is that the reference to `self.tabBarController.tabBar` is not valid in the scope of `AnotherViewController`, but it should be, right? After all, I can do things like `self.tabBarController.selectedSegmentIndex = N` in `AnotherViewController` without issue.

I have even tried changing `showActionSheet:` so that the last line is `[sheet showFromView:self.window]`. Certainly my `_window` should be globally accessible?

I'm obviously missing something fundamental here but I am not sure what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that your AppDelegate conforms to the UIActionSheetDelegate protocol?

Comment: Yes, and I have tested it from within by calling `showActionSheet` in `LYAppDelegate`.

Comment: And have you made sure you're calling this from the main thread?

Comment: Would I have to do anything out of the ordinary to call it from the main thread? I am calling it from `AnotherViewController` using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. There are no web service calls, nothing asynchronous going on. Is there something further I should do to ensure it is called from the main thread?

Comment: Just to be sure, I created a method called `-(void)callActionSheet` in  `AnotherViewController` with code `[(LYAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] showActionSheet];`, then I changed the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(calLActionSheet:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];`

Comment: Hmm. `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` happens on the main thread. Have you tried checking if you can see the tabBar with something like: `NSLog(@"Window: %@; tabbar: %@",[appDelegate.window description], [appDelegate.tabBarController.tabBar description]);`

Comment: Yes, they are both `(null)` - explains the problem - but how to fix it? Why are they null

Comment: Really not sure. I'd have to see more code. Is this on the iPad? There is a problem there where the appDelegate's window is not completely loaded until everything else in the same .xib file is, and it would return the same error, but this wouldn't apply to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Have you tried on an actual device or just the simulator?

Comment: This is a Universal app but I only have an iPhone `mainWindow` xib... Only tried on the simulator.